# How to use EXECUTE FORMAT ... USING in Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, format, plpgsql, using, execute

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummytest_insert_trigger()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   v_partition_name    VARCHAR(32);
BEGIN
   IF NEW.datetime IS NOT NULL THEN
      v_partition_name := 'dummyTest';            
      EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES ($1,$2)',v_partition_name)using NEW.id,NEW.datetime;            
   END IF;                  
   RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

I'm trying to insert using:

```
INSERT INTO dummytest VALUES(1,'2013-01-01 00:00:00+05:30');
```

But it's showing error as:

```
ERROR: function format(unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function "dummytest_insert_trigger" line 8 at EXECUTE statement
```

I'm unable get the error.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using? AFAIK, the `format` function was added in 9.1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your function could look like this in Postgres 9.0 or later:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummytest_insert_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   v_partition_name text := quote_ident('dummyTest');  -- assign at declaration
BEGIN
   IF NEW.datetime IS NOT NULL THEN
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || v_partition_name || ' VALUES ($1,$2)'
      USING NEW.id, NEW.datetime;              
   END IF;                    

   RETURN NULL;  -- you sure about this?
END
$func$;
```

About `RETURN NULL`:

- [To ignore result in BEFORE TRIGGER of PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774157/to-ignore-result-in-before-trigger-of-postgresql/31892633#31892633)

I would advice against mixed case identifiers. With `format(... %I ...)` or `quote_ident()`, you get a table named `"dummyTest"`, which you'll have to double quote for the rest of its existence. Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Use lower case instead:

```
quote_ident('dummytest')
```

There is really no point in using dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` as long as you have a static table name. But that's probably just the simplified example?

Aside: this kind of trigger is obsolete with [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) in Postgres 10 or later.

Comment: :: yes.It's a simplified eample.Actually I'm using database partitioning for that table name is generating dynamically ,still IT's not working for simpler part.
I used all above with dummytest in lowercase on postgres 9.1 and I'm getting following error 

ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO dummytest VALUES ($1,$2)"
PL/pgSQL function "dummytest_insert_trigger" line 7 at EXECUTE statement

Comment: @mona: Sounds like you may be creating an infinite loop with your triggers. It' your responsibility to avoid that.

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter  : Yes It was my mistake.Thanks your solution worked. :) :)

Comment: This was perfect ."There is really no point in using dynamic SQL with EXECUTE as long as you have a static table name. ".

Answer (score 6):

You need explicit cast to `text`:

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES ($1,$2)'::text ,v_partition_name) using NEW.id,NEW.datetime;
```

Comment: yes.I got the problem.It was causing due to version only.I was using version 9.0.Thanks

Comment: @mona: Once you upgrade: a cast to `text` is *not* necessary, `text` being the default type for quoted literals.