# Issues with PL/pgSQL code

Tags: function, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am not very much experienced in plpgsql so I am having 2 questions here.

1. Is it possible in Postgres to use cursors the way we use in dynamic sql's for plsql? Basically I did not want to use procedure in plsql so I created a cursor which will hold the output of my dynamic query and then I use that value in a loop inside another query to get my output displayed on the screen. The same thing I am trying to with Postgres but not able to do so.
2. Is it possible to in such situation to avoid creating a permanent function to accomplish this?

Here is my oracle script which runs fine:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_tables IS
     SELECT  NAME,
'SELECT PROPERTY_VALUE FROM '
         || USERNAME
         || '.P_PROPERTY WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = ''VERSION'''
                 AS dsql
       FROM CB_DATASOURCE
      WHERE (UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE 'NAV_PS_%' or UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE 'CBPS_%' or UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE 'DEFAULTPS');
  CURR_VERSION VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR r_tables IN cur_tables LOOP
   begin
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE r_tables.dsql INTO CURR_VERSION;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r_tables.NAME || ': ' || CURR_VERSION);
    exception
     when others then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r_tables.NAME || ' no table');
   end;   
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

and here is my postgres function which I am not able to get it working but eventually would like to refrain from using a permanent function

```
create or replace function upgrade_version() returns setof record as $$ 
declare
 r record;
 loopy record;
 isql text;
 CURR_VERSION text;
begin
 for r in SELECT 'SELECT PROPERTY_VALUE FROM '
         || USERNAME
         || '.P_PROPERTY WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = ''VERSION'''
                 AS dsql
       FROM CB_DATASOURCE
      WHERE (UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE 'NAV_PS_%' or UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE 'CBPS_%' or UPPER(USERNAME) LIKE 'DEFAULTPS') loop
  isql := r.dsql;
  EXECUTE isql INTO CURR_VERSION;
  RETURN next loopy;
 end loop;
 return;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

I would really appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: The name of the procedural language is [`PL/pgSQL` or simply `plpgsql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html). And the name of the RDBMS is [`PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). At least that you could have found out yourself. Please present a halfway decent question, and don't be afraid of [formatting aids](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I would try to put a decent question next time onwards.

Comment: Aside: Do not quote the language name in `LANGUAGE plpgsql`. It's an identifier, not a string. Tolerated for now, but may go away in future releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you seem to be trying should work with a [**`DO`** statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html#):

```
DO
$do$ 
DECLARE
   r record;
   curr_version text;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN 
      SELECT name, format($$
         SELECT property_value
         FROM   %I.p_property
         WHERE  property_name = 'VERSION'$$, username) AS dsql
      FROM   cb_datasource
      WHERE  upper(username) LIKE ANY ('{NAV_PS_%, CBPS_%, DEFAULTPS}')
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE r.dsql INTO curr_version;
         RAISE NOTICE '%: %', r.name, curr_version;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RAISE NOTICE '%: no table', r.name;
      END;   
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

#### Major points

- You cannot `RETURN` from a `DO` statement, but you can `RAISE` notices et al.
  Seems to be perfect for you since you `eventually would like to refrain from using a permanent function`.
  Note that the default procedural language for `DO` statements is still `plpgsql`.
- In Postgres, unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case (as opposed to Oracle, where they are upper-cased).
- To catch exceptions in a loop you need to wrap the body in a separate block. [Read the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)
- You need to sanitize identifiers in dynamically built SQL strings lest you are vulnerable to SQL injection and other problems from non-standard names. Your Oracle code is lacking there as well.
  I am using `format()` with `%I` for the purpose. More info:
  [How to use EXECUTE FORMAT ... USING in postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065271/how-to-use-execute-format-using-in-postgres-function/14066715#14066715)
- Shortened your `WHERE` clause with [`ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486)
- You are aware that `_` is a placeholder character in `LIKE` patterns? For literal `_`, escape it: `\_`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid creating a permanent function by using a DO $$ $$ script: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-do.html

However, I'm not clear on how you'd avoid having PL/pgSQL code entirely, given that you're defining a cursor based on the contents of another query.  You're using PL/SQL code in Oracle; why wouldn't you need procedural code in PostgreSQL?

You can certainly use OPEN CURSOR FOR EXECUTE in your PL/pgSQL function if you have a preference for cursors, but you can't use the same structure you have in Oracle; in PL/pgSQL, you can't DECLARE a cursor as a string substitution.  That's only done during OPEN: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-cursors.html

Aside from the thought that having an EAV settings table for each user isn't a great design ...