# postgresql, could not identify column in record data type

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, execute

I'm trying use dynamic SQL with Postgresql. I'm stuck with trying to use `id` field from `db_row` RECORD in another `EXECUTE` statement. Field `id` is set in record variable but I still get error:

```
ERROR:  could not identify column "id" in record data type
LINE 1: SELECT $1.id FROM audit.portfolio WHERE alter_type = 'INSERT...
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT $1.id FROM audit.portfolio WHERE alter_type = 'INSERT' AND id = $1.id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 14 at EXECUTE
```

This is my data and test function:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.portfolio
(
  id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER VARYING,
  CONSTRAINT portfolio_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit.portfolio
(
  alter_type TEXT,
  id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name       CHARACTER VARYING,
  CONSTRAINT portfolio_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE
);

INSERT INTO public.portfolio (id, name) VALUES (1, 'NAME 1'), (2, 'NAME 2');

-- temp function
DO $$
DECLARE
  db_row RECORD;
  pk_val BIGINT;

BEGIN

  FOR db_row IN EXECUTE format(
      'SELECT *, 100 AS created_by_id, %L::TIMESTAMP AS creation_time FROM public.%I ORDER BY %I',
      '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 'portfolio', 'id', 'id')
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'db_row.id: %', db_row.id;
    EXECUTE
    format(
        'SELECT $1.%I FROM audit.%I WHERE alter_type = %L AND %I = $1.%I',
        'id', -- this will be dynamic and change when table change
        'portfolio', -- this will be dynamic and change when table change
        'INSERT',
        'id', -- this will be dynamic and change when table change
        'id' -- this will be dynamic and change when table change
    )
    INTO pk_val
    USING db_row;
    RAISE NOTICE 'pk_val: %', pk_val;
  END LOOP;
END$$;
```

It seems like postgres `EXECUTE ... USING db_row` does not see full structure of `db_row` that is like row from `porfolio` table.

My final goal is to create function that will take any existing table name 
do this:

```
EXECUTE
    format(
        'SELECT $1.%I FROM audit.%I WHERE alter_type = %L AND %I = $1.%I',
        'primary_key_col', 
        'table_name', 
        'INSERT',
        'primary_key_col', 
        'primary_key_col'
    )
    INTO pk_val
    USING db_row
```

How to tell postgres to use `db_row.id` value in this `EXECUTE` statement?

Comment: maybe this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065271/how-to-use-execute-format-using-in-postgres-function

Comment: In this example I know table name, columns and primary key name. But in real code I won't. So I can't use `USING db_row.id, db_row.col2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a parameter (`db_row`) of type `record` to an SQL statement, but such a value has no known structure for the SQL engine. You cannot even cast it to the table type.

One ugly workaround I can think of it to cast the record to its text representation (which works with a call to the type output function) and then cast the test to the desired table type.

This is sample code that illustrates what I mean:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   r record;
   n name;
BEGIN
   /* find all tables with a column "oid" */
   FOR r IN
      SELECT t.*
         FROM pg_class t
              JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = t.oid
         WHERE a.attname = 'oid'
   LOOP
      /* get the table name */
      EXECUTE format(
                 'SELECT ($1::text::%s).relname',
                 'pg_class'
              ) INTO n USING r;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Table name: %', n;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```