# How to insert variable value into JSONPath string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-concatenation, jsonpath

I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_function1(arg1 text DEFAULT 'Miha'::text)
 RETURNS SETOF declarations
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
select * from declarations where data @? '$.** ? (@ == $1)';
$function$
```

How to substitute variable `arg1` for `$1` in the JSONPath expression?

```
select * from declarations where data @? '$.** ? (@ == $1)';
```

If I use a string literal, all is good:

```
select * from declarations where data @? '$.** ? (@ == "Sergey")';
```

Comment: Either:  1. Use `jsonb_path_exists()`.  That can take a `vars` parameter that you can create with `jsonb_build_object()`;  or 2. Use `format()` or text concatenation to build the query.  e.g. `format('$.** ? (@ == "%s")', arg1)`

Comment: Just for sake of completeness `select * from declarations where data @? format('$.** ? (@ == "%s")', arg1)::jsonpath;` it must be cast to jsonpath type.

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the function parameter into a string and cast to `jsonpath` (as suggested in comments). But nested string values are **double-quoted** in a `jsonpath` expression (while Postgres string types use single-quotes). So neither [`format()` nor any of the `quote_*()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) family of functions handles that properly.

For string-concatenation, you could double-quote manually, escaping nested double-quotes if any. **Or** you cast to `json` / `jsonb` and back to `text` to make Postgres do the work for you, reliably. Either with `jsonb_build_object('arg1', arg1)` to build the jsonb argument for the function call. Or with `to_json(arg1)::text` for string concatenation.

#### Function [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

The largely equivalent function `jsonb_path_exists()` offers the option to pass parameters to the `jsonpath` expression. That's not implemented for the operator `@?`. A clean & safe way is to use `jsonb_path_exists()`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_function1(arg1 text DEFAULT 'Miha')
  RETURNS SETOF public.declarations       -- schema-qualify to be safe
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS    -- PARALLEL SAFE in Postgres 9.6 or later
$func$
SELECT *
FROM   public.declarations
WHERE  jsonb_path_exists(target => data
                       , path   => 'strict $.** ? (@ == $arg1)'      -- can use a param ...
                       , vars   => jsonb_build_object('arg1', arg1)  -- ... which is defined in next arg
                       , silent => true);                            -- to behave exactly like original operator @?
$func$;
```

Using the optional, more verbose function call with named parameters for clarity. See:

- [Functions with variable number of input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782199/functions-with-variable-number-of-input-parameters/16789179#16789179)

**Major downside**: Postgres indexes are bound to operators, not functions. So this form gets no index support. No good for big tables. Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

#### Operator [`@?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_function1(arg1 text DEFAULT 'Miha')
  RETURNS SETOF public.declarations
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT *
FROM   public.declarations
WHERE  data @? format('strict $.** ? (@ == $s)'  -- note: strict
                    , to_json(arg1)::text        -- safe conversion
                     )::jsonpath;
$func$;
```

I added `strict` as advised in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#STRICT-AND-LAX-MODES):

> To avoid surprising results, we recommend using the `.**` accessor only in the strict mode.

Wouldn't break in this particular case, but it's still cheaper.

You could also use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a PL/pgSQL function and pass the `jsonpath` expression in a `USING` clause. (The same issue with double-quoting applies.) See:

- [How to use EXECUTE FORMAT ... USING in Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065271/how-to-use-execute-format-using-in-postgres-function/14066715#14066715)
- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)

#### Index

```
CREATE INDEX declarations_gin_idx ON public.declarations USING gin (data);
```

**Important** detail for your particular `jsonpath` expression, quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH):

> The `jsonb_ops` operator class also supports `.*` and `.**` accessors,
> but the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class does not.

So you cannot use the more optimized operator class `jsonb_path_ops` for this. See:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)